# How to design property files

Tags: java, design, design-patterns

I always wonder what is the best way to design your property files. I have few questions that I didn't find an answer to them

1. Do we place all our labels / error messages in one file?
2. Do we split the files, one for labels and another for errors (more logical and practical solution)
3. Do we make a property file per project or per module or per page?
4. How to prevent duplication in property files? is there a way other than using a database?

This question **IS NOT** about how to create/update/load property files but rather what is the best practice to use them. Is there a common design pattern for them or not.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest my points but updates are most welcome

> Do we place all our labels / error messages in one file?

You can separately define labels and error message as it will provide you more loosely coupled design.

> Do we make a property file per project or per module or per page?

Property file per project is the best scenario as you can refer the single property file and load the same into cache , that will provide performance improvement also. But also we have to take care of the file size , It should not exceed to larger file size because larger file can cause problems in terms of performance.

> How to prevent duplication in property files? is there a way other than using a database?

you can very well design a tool or program which will check if the same property has been introduced earlier and if it is not then only introduce the property into the file else use the previous one's.